# Парсинг XML в объект

Tags: php, xml, парсер

**Имеем XML документ:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<main>
    <metadata>
        <title><![CDATA[Title]]></title>
        <styles><![CDATA[On]]></styles>
        <script name="a"><![CDATA[Off]]></script>
        <script name="b"><![CDATA[On]]></script>
    </metadata>
    <data>
        <text><![CDATA[This is simple text for this data]]></text>
        <img><![CDATA[http://www.fullhdoboi.com/wallpapers/thumbs/6/kartinka-apelsiny-1885.jpg]]></img>
        <codes>
            <data_code><![CDATA[sH37Djcd]]></data_code>
            <document_code><![CDATA[lnbtyuJBTc11933774]]></document_code>
        </codes>
    </data>
</main>
```

**Есть php код:**

```
$xml_file = simplexml_load_file($data); /// $data - наш XML документ
/// Распечатка свойств объекта
echo "<pre>";
print_r($xml_file);
echo "</pre>";
/// Вывод script со значением атрибута (name) b
echo $xml_file->metadata->script[1];
```

1. Я не получаю при распечатке объекта данных из CDATA, как исправить?
2. Как вы можете видеть есть два одинаковых тега, но с разным содержимым атрибута, как сделать так чтобы я мог вызывать не по индексу, а по ключу?

Comment: Это `$xml_file = simplexml_load_file($data, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);`?

Comment: @Visman да я пробовал это, однако при выводе всех свойств меняется структура и пропадают атрибуты...кстати вы ничего не знаете насчет второго вопроса?